# Why can't you use push connectors to extend a short wire when they are used like that when installing LED pot lights in parallel?

Tags: electrical, wiring

A typical led pot lights installation looks like this, with two or three ways push connectors in the box used to connect this light to the previous one and to extend the wire to the next one

When you need to extend a wire that is short why can't you use a two ways push connector the same way? (let's say it is close to a pot light so by removing the pot light it is at an arm length distance in the ceiling so you can practically reach to it)

[image]

Comment: Is the wire not reaching into the box at all, or is it reaching into the box but not far enough?  Also, what wiring method is being used here?

Comment: not at all it is like half foot short

Comment: What sort of wiring method are you using then? NM cable? Armored or metal-clad cable? A conduit of some sort?

Comment: I am using three wire NM Cable 14/2  https://www.rona.ca/en/nmd-90-electrical-wire-47174876-1798004?viewStore=55070&cq_src=google_ads&cq_cmp=8143180960&cq_con=88023293927&cq_term=&cq_med=&cq_plac=&cq_net=u&cq_pos=&cq_plt=gp&&cm_mmc=shopping_google-_-8143180960-_-88023293927-_-pla-468292287757&gclid=CjwKCAjwkdL6BRAREiwA-kiczE1-IAA7926emZCVt-ioDS-RZSwpvcBf3feV4tdow1xPjxz4WBFqohoCPTAQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds

Comment: It's legal in the pot-light application because it's still an "accessible junction-box" where the connection is made. It's got nothing to do with the style of connector.

Answer (score 2):

### Use a NM splice kit

These sort of rework applications are precisely why Tyco and others make special [NM splice kits](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Tyco-Electronics-Romex-Splice-Kit-2-Wire-1-Clam-A22899-000/202204326) designed to provide a reliable, secure, self-insulated connection between NM cables without the need for a junction box to enclose it. So, I would use one of those to whack an extra length of 14/2 NM onto the too-short wire (make sure to follow the instructions on the splice kit carefully!), and then proceed as normal.

Comment: I thought it wasnt to code to use these for extensions?

Comment: @redlude97 -- the language on these has changed around several times, and the OP's in Canada anyway...

Answer (score 0):

Replace the pot light with a junction box and extend it in there to your new location using push connectors or wire nuts

Comment: I am looking for a solution without a box which they say it will have to be accessible. THis is in the ceiling, it will look ugly

Comment: Does the ceiling lead to the attic? You can put the junction box up there if its accessible. Otherwise there are no options that meet code. There are connectors that dont need a box but cannot be used to extend circuits only for repair

Comment: it is a basement ceiling. finished